# Can't fix `NotFoundException` error when calling SendApiAsset in AWS CLI

Tags: boto3, aws-cli, sendasynchronousrequest, data-exchange, similarweb

Recently, I have been trying to access a data products from the AWS marketplace using the AWS CLI. I have an active subscription on the product; however, I get the `NotFoundException` error whenever I try to access any of the product's endpoints via an API call.

Similar to the [AWS workshop training](https://catalog.us-east-1.prod.workshops.aws/workshops/e5548031-3004-49ad-89be-a13e8cd616f6/en-US/subscriber-and-export-data/api-call) in Task 2 i.e. Make API call with AWS CLI, I attempted to make calls to SimilarWeb endpoints using the code below:

```
aws dataexchange send-api-asset \
--data-set-id **************************** \
--revision-id **************************** \
--asset-id ******************************* \
--method GET \
--path '' \
--query-string-parameters 'param1=value1,param2=value2' \
--output json | jq -r '.Body' | jq '.params.querystring'
```

but resulted in the following error:

```
An error occurred (NotFoundException) when calling the SendApiAsset operation: No method found matching route / for http method GET
```

How can I fix this error or correctly make API call to the SimilarWeb's endpoint from AWS CLI or using boto3? Please post your suggestions. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each API on AWS Data Exchange will have different signatures, which will inform what paths are supported and how to format any additional parameters. The `NotFoundException` typically occurs when the path does not exist within the provider's API. In this case, SimilarWeb, the provider, has a series of endpoints and they are generally described on [their website](https://developers.similarweb.com/reference), but none conform to the root path as specified in the example CLI invocation you provided. Depending on which endpoint you'd like to call, the values for `path` and `query-string-parameters` will need to change.

For example, for the [website description endpoint](https://developers.similarweb.com/reference/website-description), the `path` would be something like `/v1/website/bbc.com/general-data/description` and the `query-string-parameters` would be something like `domain=bbc.com`. A call using the CLI would then look something like this:

```
aws dataexchange send-api-asset \
--data-set-id <dataset_id> \
--revision-id <revision_id> \
--asset-id <asset_id> \
--region us-east-1 \
--method GET \
--path '/v1/website/bbc.com/general-data/description' \
--query-string-parameters 'domain=bbc.com'
```

The API data product should contain an OpenAPI specification that helps illustrate supported paths and what parameters are associated with each.